# Bash script - If conditional with [ ]

Tags: bash

I have the code below and am receiving the following error output:

```
Enter your exam score
40
./if2.sh: line 6: 40: No such file or directory
Very well done. You have an A grade.
```

I'm using bash 4.1.2(1) on CentOS.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script demonstrates the if-then-elif format.

echo "Enter your exam score"
read exam_pct
if [ $exam_pct < 40 ]
then
    echo "Sorry, you have failed."
elif [ $exam_pct > 70 ]
then 
    echo "Very well done. You have an A grade."
else
    echo "Well done. You passed."
fi
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: `[` is a command.  Shell scripts are much clearer if it is spelled correctly, and the correct spelling is `test`.  When you write `if test $exam_pct < 40` is is much more obvious that you are trying to invoke the command `test $exam_pct` with input redirected from the file `40`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
if [ $exam_pct < 40 ]
```

with

```
if (( exam_pct < 40 ))
```

Take a look at the link given by Bill. Unix shell history is full of non-intuitive extensions. Depending on your case, Bash should be safe to use though.
If you are interested in shell history take a look at http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/

Comment: Is there any particular reason why I need [[ ]]? All the material I've read states [ ] unless that is only meant to be used on an older version of bash.

Comment: [[ ]] is a bash extension. It makes test condition a bit more versatile.

Comment: `<` is lexicographic in `[[`. If $exam_pct were 127, the condition would evaluate true. Use `-lt` and `-gt` just as with `[`, or use `((`

Comment: You want `(( exam_pct < 40 ))` for math, not `[ ]` _or_ `[[ ]]`. `-lt` and `-gt` inside `[[ ]]` aren't incorrect, but they are unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: True! listen to @CharlesDuffy

Comment: ...also, if you use `[[ ]]`, you don't need to quote -- it's special syntax that prevents string-splitting and glob expansion implicitly.

Comment: @log0 ...you also don't need the '$' _or_ the quotes when using `(( ))`; I took the liberty of an appropriate edit.

Comment: But! you shouldn't pass user input to an arithmetic expression, because it might blow up with an arithmetic syntax error. (Try typing `40 foo` or even `40foo` to the question.)

Comment: There is no "awkward half working extension" here.  `[` is a command.  It can take input redirected from a file.  The `<` operator is extremely useful for file redirection, and should not be used in the wrong context as a binary operator.  The syntax is often confusing, but it is not accurate to describe this as a "half working extension".  In fact, `[[` is the non-portable extension.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes I was expecting that reaction. Let's call it extremely non intuitive behaviours. I like this link http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not portable to POSIX, granted, but `[[` isn't strictly a bashism either; its usage here is identical in ksh or zsh as well. And, well, this _is_ a question tagged bash.

Answer (score 4):

`if [ $exam_pct < 40 ]` should be `if [ "$exam_pct" -lt 40 ]`

`if [ $exam_pct > 70 ]` should be `if [ "$exam_pct" -gt 70 ]`

Please always quote your variables.

Look at this for more details - http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: ...you only need to quote your expansions in this case if you're using `[ ]`; `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` are syntax, preventing word-splitting and glob expansion regardless.

Comment: ...by the way, the ABS is a pretty awful reference; much of its advice on that page (for instance, preferring `(("$a" > "$b"))` to `(( a > b ))`) is downright harmful. (Explicit expansions result in syntax errors in the case of null contents, whereas implicit ones in a math context don't).

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on why you're getting the error you're getting: `[` isn't special syntax; it's just an [executable](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (usually provided through a builtin, though `/usr/bin/[` probably exists on your system), which by convention takes "]" as its last argument.

So when you write `[ $exam_pct < 40 ]`, what you're actually doing is starting `[` with (ideally) two arguments (the contents of `$exam_pct`, and `]`), and the contents of a file with the name `40` piped to its stdin.

Similarly, when you do `[ $exam_pct > 70 ]`, you're redirecting the output of `[ $exam_pct ]` (which will be blank, because `[` doesn't ever write to stdout) to a file called `70`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

```
if [ $exam_pct \< 40 ]
```

also works

Comment: It isn't in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/test.html, and so only works by way of a nonstandard extension. Isn't the only point to using `[` or `test` to be standards-compliant?

Comment: I don't think it's a non-standard extension, but rather a way to protect the `<` from being interpreted as a redirection operator and performing *string* comparison instead. For integer comparison, `$exam_pct -lt 40` is required. Using string comparision, `[ 100 \< 40 ]` would be true, because the comparison is lexicographic, not arithmetic.

Comment: But... but... OP needs integer comparison, not string comparison.